# How do I validate a decimal like this 00.00?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms, decimal

I am learning validation expressions and have attempted to write one to check a decimal like the example below but I am having some issues.

The number to validate is like this:

00.00 (any 2 numbers, then a ., then any 2 numbers)

This is what I have:

```
^[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}$
```

This expression returns false but from a tutorial I read I was under the understanding that it should be written like this:

```
^ = starting character 
[0-9] = any number 0-9
{2} = 2 numbers 0-9
[.] = full stop
$ = end
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that pattern, but `[.]` can be written as `\.`, and if you want to support other numeral systems (e.g [Eastern Arabic Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals)), you should replace `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Regex?

Comment: I am using regex because I will have to do several other types of validation as well following this one.

Comment: What's the difference between [.] and \.

Answer (score 4):

Use the right tool for the job. If you're parsing decimals, use `decimal.TryParse` instead of Regex.

```
string input = "00.00";
decimal d;
var parsed = Decimal.TryParse(input, out d);
```

---

If the requirement is to always have a 2 digits then a decimal point then 2 digits you could do:

```
var lessThan100 = d < 100m;
var twoDecimals = d % 0.01m == 0;
var allOkay = parsed && lessThan100 && twoDecimals;
```

---

So our results are

```
Stage       | input = "" | "abc" | "00.00" | "123" | "0.1234"
-------------------------------------------------------------
parsed      | false      | false | true    | true  | true
lessThan100 | -          | -     | true    | false | true
twoDecimals | -          | -     | true    | -     | false
```

---

Although if you really need it to be that exact format then you could do

```
var separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
var allOkay = isOkay && input.Length == 5 && input[2] == separator;
```

Comment: How does this work, does it matter what I set in the input as long as it's numbers? for example could input = "99.99" and achieve the same test?

Comment: @connersz Yes, any parsable decimal number will return `true` if this passes, `false` if it does not.  So 123.45 would pass 123.a5 would not.

Comment: Of course input should come from wherever you are checking; a text box, some data from a web request, random characters. I just "hard-coded" it here to make the example compilable straight away.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it is only ever 2 digits before and 2 digits after the decimal place?

Comment: Is there a way to use regular expressions so I can also apply the same method for strings etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use Regex then the following works as required:

```
Regex.IsMatch("12.34", @"^([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})$")
```

Regex explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `()` - match what's inside of brackets
- `[0-9]{2}` exactly 2 characters in the range 0 - 9
- `\.` - full stop (escaped)
- `$` - end of string